# Android Studio virtual machine

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I can't open the program on the Android Studio virtual machine:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\L\StudioProjects\contador\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\L.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I've already installed some SDK tools and it didn't make a difference. All Android Studio licenses are accepted, all right. I really need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which java version are you using? You may try to install java 8 and set it as default. I had the same problem with Java 16